# how to create hasMany association in sequelize

Tags: sequelize.js

I want to add offerzone table as a foreign key in offerset table. using sequelize and below model is written in angularjs.

```
module.exports = function(sequelize, DataTypes) {
let offerzone = sequelize.define('offerzone', {
title: DataTypes.STRING,
moid: DataTypes.INTEGER,
seoTandC: DataTypes.STRING,
isActive: DataTypes.BOOLEAN,
set: DataTypes.ARRAY(DataTypes.STRING),
isDeleted: DataTypes.BOOLEAN
}, {
classMethods: {
  associate: function(models) {
    offerzone.belongsToMany(models.offerset, {
      through: 'models.offerset'
      foreign-key: 'offerzone'
      as: 'offerset'
    });

    // associations can be defined here
  }
}
});
return offerzone;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

To define hasMany association in sequelize the steps are the following if you want to have for example Videos hasMany Comments.

In video you will have something like that for you **video** model

```
module.exports = function (sequelize, DataTypes) {
    var Video = sequelize.define("Video", {
         author: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING,
            allowNull: false
        }
    }, {
        classMethods: {
            associate: function (models) {
                Video.hasMany(models.Comment, {foreignKey: 'videoid', onDelete: 'cascade', hooks: true});
            }
        }
    });
    return Video;
};
```

The comment model will be:

```
module.exports = function (sequelize, DataTypes) {
    var Comment = sequelize.define("Comment", {
        commentary: {
            type: DataTypes.TEXT,
            allowNull: false
        }
    }, {
        classMethods: {
            associate: function (models) {
                Comment.belongsTo(models.Video, {foreignKey: 'videoid', allowNull: false});
            }
        }
    });
    return Comment;
};
```

The part `onDelete: 'cascade', hooks: true` means that if you delete the videos the Comments will be also deleted